# Accessing db is creating issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to access various elements of a brewery. Everything works except the link and I am not sure what we are doing wrong here.

The only other thing I can think of is that the brewery db hasn't made the web link available even though it shows an a attribute. Attaching the code.

```js
var queryURL = "https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_city=" + city;

$.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET"
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $("#brew-list").empty();

    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var breweryName = $("<h1>").text(response[i].name);
        var website_URL = $("<a>").attr("href", response[i].website_url).appendTo(breweryName);
        var streetAddress = $("<h2>").text("Address: " + response[i].street);
        var city = $("<h1>").text("City: " + response[i].city);
        var phoneNum = $("<h2>").text("Phone Number: " + response[i].phone);

        $("#brew-list").append(breweryName, website_URL, streetAddress, phoneNum, city);
    }

});
```

Result so far is showing everything as expected besides the website url

Comment: Your code looks good. When you log the `response`, can you see the `website_url` in the AJAX response?

Comment: 0:
brewery_type: "micro"
city: "Seattle"
country: "United States"
id: 7499
latitude: "47.7238772"
longitude: "-122.2931111"
name: "Hellbent Brewing Company"
phone: "2063613707"
postal_code: "98125-4428"
state: "Washington"
street: "13035 Lake City Way NE"
tag_list: []
updated_at: "2018-08-24T16:35:37.928Z"
website_url: "http://www.hellbentbrewingcompany.com"    thats an example of console logged

Comment: Your `<a>` element has no text content so how do you expect to see / click on it? You're also appending it to your `<h1>` but then adding it again to `#brew-list`. You probably don't want to do both